# Get list of links from large text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge text file, 20k+ lines, and I want to extract links from it.

What I need is a regular expression that generates a clean list of links.

The links i need start with `http://` (without `www`) and end with `.html`

What would the expression look like?

Comment: Is Notepad++ an absolute requirement? grep would be perfect for this job. I'm thinking with Notepad++ you'll have to run the regex search/replace more than once (once to find and somehow flag your links, another time to delete all non-link text)...

Comment: I found a way to do it but with several steps:

step 1) Mark all lines that contain a http://
Step 2) Delete all unmarked
step 3) find everything before http:// and delete it.
Step 4) Find everything after .html and delete it.

Comment: @user3521013 that's bound to produce errors sooner or later your regex idea is way better.

Comment: For more information, here's an answer about [matching urls with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496) from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), which is listed under "Common Validation Tasks > Internet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would look like this for global websites that end with .html pages:

```
(http|https)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}.+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.].html
```

And to match exactly what you specified:

```
http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.+[a-z]{2,}\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.html
```

Just Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V in a new File and u got it.

Works for JavaScript and Notepad++ so on.

`\b` is for word boundaries that searches whole words only so if there's just this word in the text like that: `ewkgml http://test.com/a.html lamklwmwtmk` it will find it and `\B` is the negation of it so `wegniwgnwkjnhttp://test.com/a.htmllmwtlkmt34lt` will work too. `|` is the `or` statement.

Comment: What do you mean with `(\b|\B)` ?

Comment: @M42 added the answer to your question in my answer

Comment: Then you could remove it :-)

Comment: thank you i just added it cause for some reason my notepad selected more than just those strings. Or maybe it was just too late ;) anyway works fine now without the b's

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++  open the `Replace Dialog` (CTRL+H) insert

```
.*?(http://.*?\.html).*?
```

in  `Find what:` input field and

```
$1\n
```

in `Replace with:` input field

You have to check the checkbox `Regular Expression` and the chebox `. match newline`

After you have clicked `Replace all` you get a list of all links - one per line